# How to instantiate and manipulate hundreds of variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have an initial Pandas dataframe with 29 columns of interest that I, unfortunately, have to assign to individual variables manually:

```
data= pd.read_csv('data.csv')

Prediction0 = data.ix[:, 'prediction0'].tolist()
Prediction1 = data.ix[:, 'prediction1'].tolist()
.....
Prediction29 = data.ix[:, 'prediction29'].tolist()
```

Now, I would like to put these variables in a dictionary

```
self.limit = len(data)
self.history=[]

for i in range(0,self.limit): 
        self.history.append({'Prediction0': Prediction0[i], 'Prediction1': Prediction1[i], 'Prediction2': Prediction2[i], 'Prediction3': Prediction3[i], 'Prediction4': Prediction4[i], 'Prediction5': Prediction5[i], 'Prediction6': Prediction6[i], 'Prediction7': Prediction7[i], 'Prediction8': Prediction8[i], 'Prediction9': Prediction9[i], 'Prediction10': Prediction10[i], 'Prediction11': Prediction11[i], 'Prediction12': Prediction12[i], 'Prediction13': Prediction13[i], 'Prediction14': Prediction14[i], 'Prediction15': Prediction15[i], 'Prediction16': Prediction16[i], 'Prediction17': Prediction17[i], 'Prediction18': Prediction18[i], 'Prediction19': Prediction19[i], 'Prediction20': Prediction20[i], 'Prediction21': Prediction21[i], 'Prediction22': Prediction22[i], 'Prediction23': Prediction23[i], 'Prediction24': Prediction24[i], 'Prediction25': Prediction25[i], 'Prediction26': Prediction26[i], 'Prediction27': Prediction27[i], 'Prediction28': Prediction28[i], 'Prediction29': Prediction29[i]})
```

Later on, this dictionary becomes a numpy Array

```
predictionList=numpy.array([list(map(lambda x: ((x["Prediction0"], x["Prediction1"], x["Prediction2"], x["Prediction3"], x["Prediction4"], x["Prediction5"], x["Prediction6"], x["Prediction7"], x["Prediction8"], x["Prediction9"], x["Prediction10"], x["Prediction11"], x["Prediction12"], x["Prediction13"], x["Prediction14"], x["Prediction15"], x["Prediction16"], x["Prediction17"], x["Prediction18"], x["Prediction19"], x["Prediction20"], x["Prediction21"], x["Prediction22"], x["Prediction23"], x["Prediction24"], x["Prediction25"], x["Prediction26"], x["Prediction27"], x["Prediction28"], x["Prediction29"])),self.history[index]))])
```

As you can see, I have to instantiate and manipulate each of these variables manually one by one.

Now, unfortunatelly, **I have a new Pandas Dataframe with 990 columns of interest (the other 10 I dont want)**. As you might imagine, instantiating and manipulating manually such number of variables in the above code seems to be quite unfeasible. Is there any efficient way to do such tasks with a very high number of variables in Python?

Comment: Why did not you run a loop from 0 to 29?

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong. You just want to convert the csv data into numpy array?

Comment: How to add new variables and adapt each part of my code to such a loop? that's what I dont know how to do :-(

Comment: @ChayanBansal I want to convert just some columns of the dataframe and put them in a numpy array one by one in a for loop (like the last part of my code that works for 29 columns).

Comment: @mad You seem to be doing a lot of work for no apparent reason? I'm not sure... but if columns contain a common pattern then maybe something like: `prediction_list = data.filter(regex='^prediction\d+$').values` might be it?

Comment: @JonClements the question here is that some functions that I will use accept numpy arrays only as input, others only accept dictionaries. I am trying your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: @mad the `.values` attribute of a dataframe/series gives you the underlying numpy array(s)